# grep with extended regex over multiple lines

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to get a pattern over multiple lines. I would like to ensure the line I'm looking for ends in \r\n and that there is specific text that comes after it at some point. The two problems I've had are I often get unmatched parenthesis in groupings or I get a positive match when there is none. Here are two simple examples.

```
echo -e -n "ab\r\ncd" | grep -U -c -z -E $'(\r\n)+.*TEST'
```

**grep: Unmatched ( or \(**
What exactly is unmatched there? I don't get it.

```
echo -e -n "ab\r\ncd" | grep -U -c -z -E $'\r\n.*TEST'
```

**1**
There is no TEST in the string, so why does this return a count of 1 for matches?

I'm using grep (GNU grep) 2.16 on Ubuntu 14. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-E` you can use `-P` for PCRE support in gnu grep to use advanced regex like this:

```
echo -ne "ab\r\ncd" | ggrep -UczP '\r\n.*TEST'
0

echo -ne "ab\r\ncd" | ggrep -UczP '\r\n.*cd'
1
```

`grep -E` matches only in single line input.