# perl binary stdin multiline regex

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I am trying to match a pattern over multiple lines. I would like to ensure the line I'm looking for ends in \r\n and that there is specific text that comes after it at some point. [I already tried in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780844/grep-with-extended-regex-over-multiple-lines) but it doesn't work without the -P switch which some versions don't have. So now I'm trying in perl.

I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
echo -e -n "ab\r\ncd" | perl -w -e $'binmode STDIN;undef $/;$_ = <>;if(/ab\r\ncd/){print "test"}'
```

I enabled slurp mode globally (`undef $/;`) which is sloppy but fine for this (I'll certainly take any better ideas). If I just do a `print` and pipe it to `od` I can see that $_ holds the correct bytes. The regex should match those same bytes but doesn't work for some reason. I can match ab\r but not ab\r\n etc.

Comment: What is the `$` after `perl -w -e` for?

Comment: @i alarmed alien it's the bash escape character. Am I using it wrong? I thought I was supposed to do $'\r' $'\n' etc

Comment: As I said in my answer, the `$` is why your code was not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works if you remove the stray `$` from the beginning of your code section.

However, it can be tightened up by using some command line switches such as `-0777`:

```
echo -e -n "ab\r\ncd" | perl -0777 -ne 'print "test" if /ab\r\ncd/'
```

Outputs:

```
test
```

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp the entire file as documented in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: The "line" we're speaking of is just the entire contents of `STDIN`, correct?

Comment: Correct.  In this case a line is the entire file because it's set to slurp mode.  If there were two files queued up, there would be two "lines".

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
echo -e -n "ab\r\ncd" | perl -w -e 'binmode STDIN;undef $/;$_ = <>;if(/ab\r\ncd/){print "test"}';
```

Output:

```
test
```

You had a stray `$` before the perl code.